# Accordion like form, will not work for me, can anyone see what i've done wrong here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm make a rather long form, and I want to be able to break the form down into tabbable section, then when leaving that last input/select box, the next section will slide open, while the previous slides shut. I'm also wantning to have the fieldset legend, clickable to achieve the same thing.

A good example of what I'm looking for can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/s4vcX/

Here is what I'm currently working with: http://jsfiddle.net/AUf3U/

If you'd like, you can see the current JavaScript code here:

```
$("fieldset label").hide();
$("fieldset ul").hide();
$("fieldset:first label").show();

// show when legend is clicked while hiding  rest
$("legend").bind("click", function () {
   $("fieldset label").not($(this).nextAll("label")).hide();
   $(this).nextAll("label").show();
});


//handle shift-tab on first input of each field set
$("fieldset").find("input:first").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if( e.shiftKey && e.which == 9 ) {
        $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").find("label").hide();
        var previous = $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").prev(".hidesfieldset");
        if(previous.length==0)
            previous = $(this).closest("form").find(".hidesfieldset:last");
        previous.find("label").show();
        previous.find("input").last().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

//handle tab on last input of each field set
$("fieldset").find("input:last").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if( !e.shiftKey && e.which == 9 ) {
        $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").find("label").hide();
        var next = $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").next(".hidesfieldset");
        if(next.length==0)
            next = $(this).closest("form").find(".hidesfieldset:first");
        next.find("label").show();
        next.find("input").first().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If someone can point out what`s going wrong here, I would be incredibly greatful, this has become a huge pain in the ass, and have to impelment this across about 50 forms, so changing the structure of my form is not necessarily a good thing.

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to [so]!  The reason why we ask for JSFiddle links to be accompanied by code is that we tend to use JSFiddle to demonstrate a problem, not to give the original code.  You  should still place your original code inside your post, so people can understand where you are coming from about your issues later, without going through a bunch of hoops.  If you'd like to learn more about Stack Overflow, please take a look at the [About] page.  Thanks, and I hope that you enjoy your experience on [the Stack Exchange network](http://stackoverflow.com)!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your input selector, since you are using element selector it selects only elements with tag `input` but in your first fieldset the last element is a `select` element.

Try to use the [:input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

```
//handle shift-tab on first input of each field set
$("fieldset").find(":input:last").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 9) {
        $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").find("label").hide();
        var previous = $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").prev(".hidesfieldset");
        if (previous.length == 0) previous = $(this).closest("form").find(".hidesfieldset:last");
        previous.find("label").show();
        previous.find("input").last().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

//handle tab on last input of each field set
$("fieldset").find(":input:last").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && e.which == 9) {
        $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").find("label").hide();
        var next = $(this).closest(".hidesfieldset").next(".hidesfieldset");
        if (next.length == 0) next = $(this).closest("form").find(".hidesfieldset:first");
        next.find("label").show();
        next.find(":input").first().focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UFPCr/)